# Update Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am  seeking for a help, its my first time in javascript. So I dont have any idea how to do this.

To do :
1. CRUD function.. 
  - it seems that create, retrieve and delete is working well. About the update I been having a hard time doing this.

Tasks

When Edit button will be click it, data will  be displayed in the input fields and as I clicke the add button it should not add another field but instead it should update the choosen data.

Please refer below and I am happy for any help and advices.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="add()"> 
        <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5>
        <tr>
            <th>Image Link</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_image"></td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="new_title"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="new_description"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

you can check the whole code here.
https://jsfiddle.net/kotesting/xpvt214o/354274/

Comment: uhoh, you seem to be missing your Javascript in a question tagged with Javascript. You should add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle javascript load type setting is onLoad, it will wrap all js stuff into

```
window.onload = function() {...}
```

Your function is out of scope, so it's undefined. You should choose either inside head or body.